# How do I disable Eclipse's find/search regex hint drop-down?

Tags: regex, eclipse, search, preferences

When searching (across files) or finding (within files), if you have regular expressions enabled and enter a certain character (backslash, opening paren, etc) it displays a drop-down box with hints in.

I don't need these hints; they get in the way of the rest of the dialog, and the stupid drop-down hijacks my home/end keys.

However, I can't find any preferences for disabling it - is there some hidden way to turn them off which I'm not aware of?

Alternatively, if I need to modify the source and rebuild, what files do I need to edit, and can I do it in a way that doesn't prevent upgrading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Eclipse Galileo 3.5)

I didn't find any obvious way to prevent the "content assistance" in that search field.

So what I usually do is: prepare the search expression in any editor I want, and copy-paste it in said search field.
A bit cumbersome, but it works nicely enough for me.

The goal: avoid this kind of situation.

[image]

---

(Eclipse Helios 3.6)

Note: according to **[bug 259592](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=259592)**, the **auto-completion is disabled by default in Eclipse Helios 3.6**.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> is available. A lightbulb is there to remind you that completion help is possible in this field.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I often do that, but I'm fed up with needing to - especially when I then might then need to make a handful of minor changes.

Comment: @Peter: see my edit for Eclipse Helios. Just added the picture to illustrate the new situation, which should be much more adapted to what you want.

Comment: Ah, I'll go check that out. Thought I had Helios, but turns out it's the milestone just before that change was implemented.

Comment: @Peter: the second picture you see comes from my current Helios Eclipse installation (i.e. I just made that screenshot): I can confirm there is no more inconvenient "content assist" popup. That seems much better that way.